# Choosing coordinate reference systems for esriGeometryPolygon in GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, esri-geodatabase, json

I extracted a layer of parcel

```
Geometry Type: esriGeometryPolygon
```

and save as JSON, this is a fragment of one row of this JSON:

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "OBJECTID": 171195,
    "APN": 102000,
    "REGION": "NWTM",
    "PIN": "001-020-00",
    "RECMAP": "0",
    "BOOK": "001",
    "PAGE": "02",
    "BLOCK": "0",
    "PARCEL": "00",
    "SUBNAME": "WINDERMERE 1",
    "TOWNSHIP": "19",
    "RANGE": "19",
    "SECTION_": "4",
    "FLOOR": 1,
    "MAPLINK": "https://gis.washoecounty.us/wrms/adocs/001/01_02",
    "FLR": 1,
    "Shape_STArea_1": null,
    "Shape.STArea()": 40750.998046875,
    "Shape.STLength()": 2505.240564500747
  },
  "geometry": {
    "rings": [
      [
        [
          2263777.609212335,
          14872215.233797088
        ],
        [
          2263817.024159752,
          14872187.984507754
        ],
        [
          2263959.1081931666,
          14872090.288180836
        ],
        [
          2263991.4057007506,
          14872067.960141502
        ],
        [
          2264044.0975245014,
          14872031.533705167
        ],
        [
          2264121.2194175012,
          14871978.218195006
        ],
        [
          2264165.213424001,
          14871947.804541923
        ],
        [
          2264167.1684725843,
          14871946.453166671
        ],
        [
          2264097.4212367497,
          14871853.810635418
        ],
        [
          2264052.752362836,
          14871884.58518017
        ],
        [
          2264007.087427918,
          14871913.861368336
        ],
        [
          2263960.4766287506,
          14871941.606391586
        ],
        [
          2263726.8081328347,
          14872077.290831506
        ],
        [
          2263722.2307141684,
          14872080.543777756
        ],
        [
          2263718.614251584,
          14872084.252103671
        ],
        [
          2263715.6897167526,
          14872088.527685672
        ],
        [
          2263713.544379834,
          14872093.24257125
        ],
        [
          2263712.2422170825,
          14872098.25601267
        ],
        [
          2263711.821942333,
          14872103.419060089
        ],
        [
          2263712.296350833,
          14872108.57718625
        ],
        [
          2263713.651335001,
          14872113.576848172
        ],
        [
          2263715.8462125026,
          14872118.268767923
        ],
        [
          2263773.5186693333,
          14872218.062203504
        ],
        [
          2263777.609212335,
          14872215.233797088
        ]
      ],
      [
        [
          2263927.7434265018,
          14872012.159400083
        ],
        [
          2263932.935345251,
          14872009.156125255
        ],
        [
          2263922.9225700013,
          14871991.847432837
        ],
        [
          2263940.2312624194,
          14871981.8343295
        ],
        [
          2263957.539626751,
          14871971.821226172
        ],
        [
          2263967.5527300835,
          14871989.128934339
        ],
        [
          2263972.744648833,
          14871986.125659503
        ],
        [
          2263970.7420281693,
          14871982.663396083
        ],
        [
          2263975.9349311665,
          14871979.660121255
        ],
        [
          2263965.9208435826,
          14871962.35110075
        ],
        [
          2263983.2295360006,
          14871952.3383255
        ],
        [
          2264000.537900336,
          14871942.32423792
        ],
        [
          2264010.5510036685,
          14871959.632930338
        ],
        [
          2264015.744234752,
          14871956.629327416
        ],
        [
          2264017.746855419,
          14871960.090606585
        ],
        [
          2264022.9387741685,
          14871957.08733175
        ],
        [
          2264012.9246865846,
          14871939.778967418
        ],
        [
          2264030.2330509163,
          14871929.76586409
        ],
        [
          2264047.5417433344,
          14871919.751776502
        ],
        [
          2264057.5548466668,
          14871937.060140833
        ],
        [
          2264062.7477496676,
          14871934.056866005
        ],
        [
          2264060.7441447526,
          14871930.594602585
        ],
        [
          2264065.937375836,
          14871927.59099967
        ],
        [
          2264055.923288252,
          14871910.282307252
        ],
        [
          2264073.231652584,
          14871900.269532003
        ],
        [
          2264085.062337585,
          14871893.426041752
        ],
        [
          2264088.8966475017,
          14871900.054637417
        ],
        [
          2264086.301180251,
          14871901.556274839
        ],
        [
          2264092.4740681686,
          14871912.22718525
        ],
        [
          2264098.8175594173,
          14871908.556588918
        ],
        [
          2264106.412032418,
          14871921.68517159
        ],
        [
          2264108.722723335,
          14871920.348560087
        ],
        [
          2264111.391025085,
          14871924.961739838
        ],
        [
          2264109.0806622505,
          14871926.298351333
        ],
        [
          2264109.917274751,
          14871927.743230335
        ],
        [
          2264110.7824305,
          14871927.24224709
        ],
        [
          2264113.871663168,
          14871932.582131423
        ],
        [
          2264113.00585125,
          14871933.083114669
        ],
        [
          2264113.842791833,
          14871934.527665585
        ],
        [
          2264098.2647389993,
          14871943.539786667
        ],
        [
          2264091.056420084,
          14871947.71005392
        ],
        [
          2264093.0587126687,
          14871951.17264542
        ],
        [
          2264077.7670765854,
          14871960.018428251
        ],
        [
          2264079.1036880836,
          14871962.329119168
        ],
        [
          2264074.4914925843,
          14871964.997749
        ],
        [
          2264073.154553,
          14871962.68738617
        ],
        [
          2264055.2661373354,
          14871973.036118753
        ],
        [
          2264048.0578184165,
          14871977.206386
        ],
        [
          2264050.060111001,
          14871980.66864942
        ],
        [
          2264034.768474918,
          14871989.515088417
        ],
        [
          2264032.0998450853,
          14871984.901580587
        ],
        [
          2264027.487649586,
          14871987.57021042
        ],
        [
          2264026.151038084,
          14871985.259519503
        ],
        [
          2264008.262622416,
          14871995.608580172
        ],
        [
          2264001.053975418,
          14871999.778847419
        ],
        [
          2264003.0565960854,
          14872003.241110839
        ],
        [
          2263987.7646319196,
          14872012.087549835
        ],
        [
          2263993.7724939175,
          14872022.472371586
        ],
        [
          2263971.27188275,
          14872035.489734001
        ],
        [
          2263948.771599669,
          14872048.507096417
        ],
        [
          2263927.7434265018,
          14872012.159400083
        ]
      ],
      [
        [
          2263777.977649916,
          14872126.658514917
        ],
        [
          2263777.112494167,
          14872127.159170084
        ],
        [
          2263774.022277251,
          14872121.820598088
        ],
        [
          2263774.888089169,
          14872121.319614835
        ],
        [
          2263774.0521328337,
          14872119.875063919
        ],
        [
          2263771.7414419167,
          14872121.210691169
        ],
        [
          2263769.072155919,
          14872116.597511418
        ],
        [
          2263771.382846836,
          14872115.261884168
        ],
        [
          2263763.787389584,
          14872102.133629583
        ],
        [
          2263770.1308808327,
          14872098.46434559
        ],
        [
          2263763.956352502,
          14872087.793107085
        ],
        [
          2263761.3608852513,
          14872089.29572875
        ],
        [
          2263757.525591083,
          14872082.667133085
        ],
        [
          2263769.355291836,
          14872075.822330505
        ],
        [
          2263786.664640419,
          14872065.806930587
        ],
        [
          2263796.6777437516,
          14872083.115294918
        ],
        [
          2263801.8706467524,
          14872080.111692004
        ],
        [
          2263803.873267416,
          14872083.573299251
        ],
        [
          2263809.0664984994,
          14872080.569696337
        ],
        [
          2263799.052410919,
          14872063.261003919
        ],
        [
          2263816.360775251,
          14872053.24822867
        ],
        [
          2263814.3584826663,
          14872049.78563717
        ],
        [
          2263831.6658627503,
          14872039.772533834
        ],
        [
          2263841.679950334,
          14872057.081554338
        ],
        [
          2263846.8718690835,
          14872054.076967172
        ],
        [
          2263852.0647720844,
          14872051.07336425
        ],
        [
          2263842.0506845005,
          14872033.764999919
        ],
        [
          2263859.359048836,
          14872023.751896583
        ],
        [
          2263876.6667570025,
          14872013.737809002
        ],
        [
          2263886.6808445826,
          14872031.046173334
        ],
        [
          2263891.8730914183,
          14872028.041914254
        ],
        [
          2263897.065994419,
          14872025.038639419
        ],
        [
          2263887.0519068353,
          14872007.730275087
        ],
        [
          2263904.360271167,
          14871997.717171751
        ],
        [
          2263935.4015476666,
          14872051.372248173
        ],
        [
          2263912.9006084166,
          14872064.389610589
        ],
        [
          2263890.4003253356,
          14872077.40762917
        ],
        [
          2263867.899714168,
          14872090.424991585
        ],
        [
          2263845.3991030008,
          14872103.442354001
        ],
        [
          2263841.3938616663,
          14872096.518483333
        ],
        [
          2263834.185542751,
          14872100.688422501
        ],
        [
          2263836.1878353357,
          14872104.151014
        ],
        [
          2263820.8961992525,
          14872112.997124918
        ],
        [
          2263818.2272413336,
          14872108.384273253
        ],
        [
          2263813.614389669,
          14872111.052575
        ],
        [
          2263812.2777781673,
          14872108.742212169
        ],
        [
          2263794.3903467506,
          14872119.090944752
        ],
        [
          2263778.8132781684,
          14872128.104378171
        ],
        [
          2263777.977649916,
          14872126.658514917
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

I try to load this JSON in a `GeoDataFrame` with this script:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import json

f = open('data.json')
data = json.load(f) 
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data))
```

I know that `GeoDataFrame` has a parameter `crs`, this is in an example:

```
 |  Constructing GeoDataFrame from a dictionary.
 |  
 |  >>> from shapely.geometry import Point
 |  >>> d = {'col1': ['name1', 'name2'], 'geometry': [Point(1,2), Point(2,1)]}
 |  >>> gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d, crs="EPSG:4326")
 |  >>> gdf
 |      col1                 geometry
 |  0  name1  POINT (1.00000 2.00000)
 |  1  name2  POINT (2.00000 1.00000)
 |  
 |  Notice that the inferred dtype of 'geometry' columns is geometry.
```

My questions is:

- What should be the `crs` that should use in my case?

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer.  What is the coordinate system referenced by the source layer from which the JSON was generated?  Obviously not EPSG:4326, but it could be any projected coordsys.

Comment: When I download the layer as a shapefile and look at the prj file, it says it's using `NAD_1983_StatePlane_Nevada_West_FIPS_2703_Feet`. EPSG:3423 appears to be a similar crs with the same parameters in the EPSG database.

Comment: @Vince I can't give you access to this specific example because of use password and I can't share, but should be similar to this layer or parcel in this open data mapserver
https://wcgisweb.washoecounty.us/arcgis/rest/services/OpenData/OpenData/FeatureServer/0/query

Comment: NAD_1983_StatePlane_Nevada_West_FIPS_2703_Feet shows as ESRI:102709 at https://epsg.io  This information should be in the question body.

Comment: @Vince What you mean is the info at the begining of the json, for instance this:
`{
 "objectIdFieldName": "OBJECTID",
 "globalIdFieldName": "",
 "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
 "spatialReference": {
  "wkid": 102709,
  "latestWkid": 3423
 },
 "hasZ": false, ...
`